# Android: array of textviews

Tags: android, textview

I am making an app in which I want to change the text of textviews from an array of strings. 
For that I need to make the array of textviews.How to do that?? Can anyone help me over this

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create TextViews like this:

```
int textViewCount = 10;

TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewCount];

for(int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) {
   textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

May be its useful for you i use button array so i am gussing textview work like that:

```
TextView[ ][ ]  _txt;   

_txt = new TextView[_dimension][_dimension]; // _dimension = 5 what you want
_txt[0][0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
_txt[0][1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
```

and more...

Comment: That was my requirement so you can use single array instead of 2d

Answer (score 3):

If you want large number of textviews, in that case to avoid OutofBound exception use following code

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView textView;
        for( i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTag(""+i);// setting tag with index i
            parent.addView(textView);
        }
        int len=parent.getChildCount();
        int j = 0;
        int requiredPosition = 5;
        while(j<len) {
            TextView tempTextView =((TextView)parent.getChildAt(i)); 
            if( tempTextView.getTag().equals(""+requiredPosition)){
                //Perform required operation
                //tempTextView.setText("");
            }
            j++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do achieve that with something like this:

```
int textvwCount = 20;//number of textview you want to use in an array

TextView[] arrTxtView = new TextView[textvwCount ]; // declare and assign array length of text views.

for(int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) { // iterate over all array items and assign them text.
  Textview txtCnt = new TextView(this);
txtCnt .settext(i);
 textViewArray[i] =txtCnt ;
}
```