# how can I change the text from several TextViews dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to set the text of some textViews already existing in a layout with a for loop. Eg. TextView_01, TextView_02, etc. IS there a way to do something like the following speculative code:

```
for(1 in 0..6){
       TextView_0(change value with i).text = something
}
```

Comment: Create an array or list with the TextViews in it.  Then you can walk them.like you normally would an array.  Or are you trying to ask something else?

Comment: you must define array of 'TextView'.
see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695052/10242802

Comment: Thanks to Tim Casteljins, the original question answers my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best way to do things, but it's probably the most universal, while avoiding creating a pre-defined array of TextViews:

```
val base = "TextView_0"

for (i in 1 until 6) {
    val textView = findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("${base}i", "id", packageName)
    textView.text = something
}
```

I changed your for loop a little bit, since you had the wrong syntax. I also replaced `..` with `until`, since `..` means *through* the right bound, which probably isn't what you want. If you do need `6` to be a value of `i`, then change it back to `..`.

---

If all the TextViews are under a single parent in XML, give that parent an ID, then loop through its children:

```
val parent = findViewById(R.id.tvParent)

for (i in 0 until parent.getChildCount()) {
    (container.getChildAt(i) as TextView).text = something
}
```

Comment: Your first solution is what I had in mind, tried it but didn't properly work, somehow it was producing some null TextViews values.  
As stated by Tim, someone asked this before and yes, the way to deal with this is with an array. Thanks ayway, will look deeper in your dynamic syntax which is what I really wanted.

Comment: How many TextViews do you have? If it's returning null values it's because one of the IDs doesn't exist. Maybe `TextView_06` doesn't exist? Check your names.

Answer (score -1):

You can use parent container

```
    for (i in 0 until container.childCount) {
        (container.getChildAt(i) as TextView).text = something
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way is to make use of DataBinding and LiveData APIs, you can assign different variables or the same variable to your TextViews' text attributes.